# How do I specify a relative change to ACL of current user/group?

Tags: acl

I have a directory that already might have some subdirectory configured `rwx` for `www-data`, but I want to make a final pass and ensure `www-data` has a full read access on the full directory.

All these are part of some bash scripting, and I need to automate this.

Ideally, I want to do:

```
chmod g+r /my/root/dir -R
```

But, of course, I'm using ACL, and I want to do it only for group `www-data`.

But using `setfacl` **will overwrite the previous permissions**. It doesn't support `+r` notation for relative permission settings (and it is not documented in the `man` page):

```
$ setfacl -m g:www-data:+r /tmp 
setfacl: Option -m: Invalid argument near character 12
```

How can I do that ? Shall I resort to nasty scripting solutions ?

It seems that there's a version of `setfacl` that support that in some Unix: 
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.bpxa500/sfacl.htm , it was also reported working on SuSE.

**EDIT:** I'm on an Ubuntu 15.10, my version of `setfacl` comes from a package named `acl` in version `2.2.52-2`.

Comment: What version of Unix/Linux are you using. My OpenSuSE system's setfacl supports the '-m' flag so that you can do setfacl -R -m group:www-data:+r /my/root/dir on it.

Comment: @darklion I've added my version of system and the package to the question. Thanks for this obvious (but forgotten) missing information. Can you trace your package as well ? (version and orgin of package ?).